# Alexa Skill Trigger Follow Up Intent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have written a smart speaker app for Google Home using DialogFlow, and am now in the process of porting it over to Alexa.

One of the fundamental differences seems to be the inability to easily trigger follow-up intents.  For example, I have a dialog that asks the user a series of questions, one after the other, before providing a result based on the answers provided. e.g. ({slot types})

- Do you like a low maintenance or working garden? {low maintenance}{working}
- Do you like a garden you can relax in? {yes/no}
- Would you like to grow vegetables in your garden? {yes/no}

This is easy to achieve using DialogFlow follow-up intents, but I have no clue where to start with Alexa and there dont seem to be many examples out there.  All I can find seems to focus on slot filling for a single dialog.

I am using my own API service to serve results (vs Lambda).

Can anybody recommend a way of achieving this in an Alexa Skill?

Comment: In your example (the bullet points) are you considering each question an intent? I would think of them as slots within an intent. If that is the case, you could use the addElicitSlotDirective(slotToElicit: string, updatedIntent?: Intent) method on the responseBuilder. If you do want to delegate an intent, you can use the addDelegateDirective(updatedIntent?: Intent) method: https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Building-Response.html

Comment: Thanks Dylan. Yes, I am considering each question as an intent, which is the approach used in DialogFlow.  I am trying to use the same backend service (which is .net c#) to answer requests from DF and AWS, so ask-sdk-for-nodejs is not really an option for me.

Comment: Without this ability to ask follow up questions to form part of a total dialog it feels like Alexa is pretty much restricted to single sentence dialogs??

Comment: Sorry, It looks like there is no ask-sdk for c#. However, you can absolutely do follow up questions and elicit different slots and/or intents with alexa skills. I have done it with node, but I can't help you with c#.

Comment: I managed to achieve this by adding one utterance to the Intent as follows:

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by adding a single utterance with three individual slots, one for each of the answers required:-
inspire me {InspireMaintenance} {InspireRelax} {InspireVeg}

These Slots back onto one SlotType - Custom_YesNo, which had Yes and No values + synonyms.  My C# service then checks for each of these required slots and where one is missing it triggers the relevant question as a response. Once all slots are filled it provides the answer.

Not as intuitive as Dialogflow and requires code to achieve what can be done without code in DF, but at least it works :)